# AngularJS Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, angularjs, django

Please note, I am a complete beginner in this stuff. I am  trying out Python and AngularJS by maintaining and extending existing project. I'm having issues figuring out what is causing errors in my project. Before adding  show/hide two different div on dropdown select in AngularJS, it was working. It returns

> CSRF verification failed

when I submit the form.

**register.html:**

```html
<div id="charkilla" ng-controller="charkilla">
  <div id="blank-ch-form-container"></div>
  <div class="charkilla-form-wrapper" ng-repeat="ch in charkillas track by $index">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'charkilla-create' %}" ng-submit="submit($event)">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <input type="hidden" name="reg" id="id_reg" value="{{ registrationid }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-value='ch.id' />
      <fieldset ng-disabled="ch_form_disability_{[{ $index }]}">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">दिशा*</span>
              <select name="ch_direction" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction">
                <option value="n">उत्तर</option>
                <option value="e">पुर्व</option>
                <option value="s">दक्षिण</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="w">पश्चिम</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <!-- Removed map_sheet_no for temporary
                                                <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">तर्फ़*</span>
                                                    <select name="ch_direction_through" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction_through">
                                                        <option value="front">Front</option>
                                                        <option value="back">Back</option>
                                                        <option value="left">Left</option>
                                                        <option selected="selected" value="right">Right</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 remove-killa-wrapper">
            <a class="remove-killa" ng-click="removeKilla($event, true, ch.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5 ">
          <span class="input-group-addon">लेन्डस्केप टाईप*</span>
          <select name="ch_landscape_type" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_landscape_type">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option value="road">सडक </option>
            <option value="main_road">मूख्य सडक</option>
            <option value="dead_end_road">मुख्य (सडक डेड इन्ड भएको)</option>
            <option value="ghar">घर</option>
            <option value="land">जग्गा</option>
            <option value="school">स्कूल</option>
            <option value="temple">मन्दिर</option>
            <option value="party_palace">पार्टी प्यालेस</option>
            <option value="wall">पर्खाल </option>
            <option value="chowk">चोक छ</option>
            <option value="pokhari">पोखरी</option>
            <option value="river">नदि</option>
            <option value="rajkulo">राजकुलो</option>
            <option value="public_land">सार्वजनिक जग्गा</option>
            <option value="college">कॉलेग</option>
            <option value="gumba">गुम्बा</option>
            <option value="gl_road">जी एल रोड (बाटो नखुलेको)</option>
            <option value="well">कुवा</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">नाम</span>
          <input type="text" name="ch_name_np" class="form-control nepalify" placeholder="नाम" ng-model="ch.ch_name_np" />
          <input type="text" name="ch_name_en" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="ch.ch_name_en" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">कित्ता</span>
          <input type="text" name="ch_kitta" class="form-control nepalify" ng-model="ch.ch_kitta" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Actual Setback</span>
          <input type="text" name="ch_actual_setback" class="form-control nepalify" placeholder="Actual Setback (m)" ng-model="ch.ch_actual_setback" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Standard Setback</span>
          <input type="text" name="ch_standard_setback" class="form-control nepalify" placeholder="Standard Setback (m)" ng-model="ch.ch_standard_setback" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="input-group col-md-5 nepalify" ng-show="ch_landscape_type == 'road' || ch_landscape_type == 'main_road' || ch_landscape_type == 'dead_end_road'">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Road width</span>
          <input type="text" name="ch_roadwidth" class="form-control" placeholder="Road width (m)" ng-model="ch.ch_roadwidth" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-button"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" ng-show="!ch_form_disability_{[{$index}]}" /></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="form-button"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit" ng-show="ch_form_disability_{[{$index}]}" ng-click="edit($event, $index)" /></div>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="add-more-link add-form-control" ng-click="addKilla($event)">Add another</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**charkilla.js:**

```js
app.controller("charkilla", function($scope, $compile, $http, $sce, HouseOwnerData, $rootScope) {
  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  }]);
  if (charkillas.length == 0) {
    angular.element("#blank-ch-form-container").append($compile("<killa></killa><killa></killa><killa></killa><killa></killa>")($scope))
  }

  //Values that are passed to killa.html angularjs template
  $scope.actionurl = ch_form_action_url;
  $scope.csrftoken = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.element("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]")[0].outerHTML);
  $scope.registrationid = registrationid;

  $scope.charkillas = [];
  for (idx in charkillas) {
    //Update ids in the HouseownerData
    HouseOwnerData.push_data('charkilla_id', charkillas[idx].pk);

    charkillas[idx].fields['id'] = charkillas[idx].pk;
    $scope.charkillas.push(charkillas[idx].fields);
    $scope['ch_form_disability_' + idx] = true;
  }

  $scope.addKilla = function(event) {
    angular.element(event.target).before($compile("<killa></killa>")($scope));
  };

  $scope.change_landscape_type = function(event, land_scape_tp) {
    if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
      $scope.ch_name_np = '-';
      $scope.ch_name_en = '-';
      $scope.road_type = true;
    } else {
      $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
      $scope.ch_name_en = $scope.ch_name_en;
      $scope.road_type = false;
    }
    if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
      $scope.ch_kitta = '-';
      $scope.kitta = true;
    } else {
      $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
      $scope.kitta = false;
    }
  }

  $scope.removeKilla = function(event, b_instance_delete, ch_id) {

    if (b_instance_delete) {
      vex.dialog.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this? ' + ch_id,
        callback: function(value) {
          if (value) {
            console.log("Delete confirmed");
            $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: '/registration/charkilla-delete/' + ch_id + '/',
            }).success(function($response) {
              console.log("Deleted");
              angular.element(event.target).parents(".charkilla-form-wrapper").slideUp(1000, function() {
                $(this).remove();
              });
            }).error(function($error) {
              console.log($error);
              vex.dialog.alert(JSON.stringify($error));
            })

          } else {
            console.log("Delete not confirmed");
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      angular.element(event.target).parents("div[class=killa]").slideUp(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.submit = function($event) {

    $event.preventDefault();

    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
      $scope.ch_name_np = '-';
      $scope.ch_name_en = '-';
      $scope.road_type = true;
    } else {
      $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
      $scope.ch_name_en = $scope.ch_name_en;
      $scope.road_type = false;
    }
    if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
      $scope.ch_kitta = '-';
      $scope.kitta = true;
    } else {
      $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
      $scope.kitta = false;
    }
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: $event.target.attributes['action'].value,
      data: angular.element($event.target).serialize()
    }).success(function($response) {
      HouseOwnerData.push_data("charkilla_id", $response.id);

      console.log(HouseOwnerData.get_data());
      angular.element($event.target).children('fieldset')[0].disabled = true;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('rootScope:redraw_indicator', $response);
    }).error(function($error) {
      console.log($error);
      vex.dialog.alert(JSON.stringify($error));
    });

  }

  $scope.edit = function($event, $index) {
    $scope['ch_form_disability_' + $index] = false;
  }

});
```

**killa.js:**

```js
app.directive("killa", function($compile) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    scope: {
      submit: '&', //Passing submit function from parent controller to child directive
      // https://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

      actionurl: '@actionurl',
      csrftoken: '@csrftoken',
      registrationid: '@registrationid',
      ch_landscape_type: '&',
    },

    templateUrl: '/static/detail-registration/templates/killa.html',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {

      $scope.change_landscape_type = function(event, land_scape_tp) {
        if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
          $scope.ch_name_np = '-';
          $scope.ch_name_en = '-';
          $scope.road_type = true;
        } else {
          $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
          $scope.ch_name_en = $scope.ch_name_en;
          $scope.road_type = false;
        }
        if (land_scape_tp == 'road' || land_scape_tp == 'main_road' || land_scape_tp == 'dead_end_road') {
          $scope.ch_kitta = '-';
          $scope.kitta = true;
        } else {
          $scope.ch_name_np = $scope.ch_name_np;
          $scope.kitta = false;
        }
      }
    },
    replace: true
  };

  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Comment: Can u try once `    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';` i had to add these lines in my DJango app to make it's form work with angularjs

Comment: I tried by keeping it in killa.js . ( app.directive("killa", function ($compiler, $httpProvider) {
 $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'; $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';  ) But the form disappear. There is also separate killa.html file which has form as register.html.

Comment: use that in `.config($httpProvider)` of angular js. not inside directive.

Comment: I kept angularApp.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
  
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'; $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]); in beginning of charkilla.js. But the form disappear.

Comment: disappears ? check the developer console. You must be getting some error]

Comment: yes , it  disappears from console also.

Comment: I think there is another cause that makes form disappear. I will check it again.

Comment: Hello Shashank Vivek

Comment: Yes, tell me Palistha

Comment: I need your help to solve django problem. Will you help me?

Comment: check https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186444/room-for-shashank-vivek-and-palistha